# Is it possible to use Agile UI as a view component of Yii2 application?

Tags: php, yii2, agiletoolkit

I saw the schema

https://github.com/atk4/ui#scope-and-goals-of-agile-ui

but it still unclear for me, how I can make ActiveForm or GridView (for example) using this toolkit? Are there some Yii components or practice code examples?

Answer (score 1):

It may require some integration. As author of Agile UI I made it as easy to integrate as possible, but some glue component would be needed. The principles are aligned so shouldn’t be hard to integrate.

If someone will implement the integration I will update this answer.